# TreeView: Reference Error to model

Tags: qt, qml

I have the following `TreeView`:

```
   TreeView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        sortIndicatorVisible: true
        model: fileSystemModel
        rootIndex: rootPathIndex
        selection: sel
        selectionMode: 2

        TableViewColumn {
            id: namecolumn
            title: "Name"
            role: "fileName"

            resizable: true
            width: parent.width-sizeWidth-dateWidth-scrollBarWidth
            delegate: ItemDelegate {
                id: fileCheckDelegate
                Row{CheckBox{
                    id: cbox
                    y: -4
                    }
                    Text{text: model.fileName
                        width: namecolumn.width-x-cbox.width
                        elide: Text.ElideRight
                    }
                 }
                ToolTip {
                    parent: fileCheckDelegate
                    visible: hovered
                    delay: 1000
                    text: qsTr(model.fileName)
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Everything is displayed correctly, but in the terminal I get many of the following messages:

```
qrc:/FileSystem.qml:49: TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileName' of null
qrc:/FileSystem.qml:57: TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileName' of null
```

The locations are in my delegate, once in `Text` `text: model.fileName` and once in `ToolTip` `text: qsTr(model.fileName)`. As I said, everything is displayed correctly but I am worried that this error might still give me problems. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: A workaround seems to be if I use `styleData.value` instead of `model.fileName`. Still, I do not understand why I cannot write `model.fileName`

Comment: I see no item with `id: model`. if you refer to `TreeView.model` it also has no property `fileName`. So, as you noticed the right way to access role is `styleData.value`.

Comment: I thought that a delegate can automatically access its views model. Also, I thought if you have a model you can do model.roleName to get the date stored in this role

Comment: @numberCruncher change `model.fileName` to `fileName`